# Are monitors with an IPS (in-plane switching) panel better for the eyes?

Tags: ophthalmology, productivity, monitor

[slothygeek](https://www.slothygeek.com/best-monitor-for-eyes/) writes:

> There are three main display panel types for screens: IPS, VA and TN
>   panels. Screens with TN panels are best for gaming but these are not
>   the best for your eyes. If you want a monitor that goes easy to your
>   eyes, you should pick a monitor with an IPS panel.

Is that claim that IPS  (in-plane switching) monitors are good for eye health by reducing eye strain backed by solid research or is it just a summary of marketing promises?

Comment: Basic information: https://www.trustedreviews.com/news/ips-vs-tn-vs-va-gaming-performance-colour-explained-2948955

Comment: Too low contrast causes eye-strain. That being said, that's a non-issue in _modern_ TN panels. 
Side note: I'm not aware of any _scientific_ study that'd compare different effect of LCD technologies on eye-strain.

Comment: American Optometric Association doesn't even mention it as a factor https://www.aoa.org/patients-and-public/caring-for-your-vision/protecting-your-vision/computer-vision-syndrome

Comment: @vartec If you don't know, you should not add to the confusion by posting yet another claim.

Comment: @pipe it's not _"another claim"_ though, the claimed disadvantage of TN is poor contrast and poor color saturation. Which used to be a problem. A decade ago.